# Is it possible to convert ReactJs JS(Virtual DOM) to JSX? i.e) ES5 to ES6

Tags: reactjs

I have done reactjs script using virtual DOM method. Now i need to convert it to JSX format. Is there any tool or plugin is available for this conversion.

Example :

**From**

```
var profile = React.createElement("div", null, 
 React.createElement("img", { src: "avatar.png", className: "profile" }),
 React.createElement("h3", null, [user.firstName, user.lastName].join(" "))
);
```

**to**

```
var profile = <div>
 <img src="avatar.png" className="profile" />
 <h3>{[user.firstName, user.lastName].join(' ')}</h3>
</div>;
```

*Note : Babel official website is converting JSX to JS.*

Answer (score 2):

Check [react-codemod](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod).

That package includes a script called `create-element-to-jsx` that converts `.createElement` calls to `jsx` elements.

You can use it like this (quoting from the link):

```
jscodeshift -t react-codemod/transforms/create-element-to-jsx.js <path>
```